# How to split text every 6 periods, but in parts shorter than 400 characters with regex

Tags: regex

this is a little difficult for me to explain.
I have a large text, 5000 characters, and i want to split it in small parts until period.

Let's say that every 6 period i want to create a new part of text, but i don't want this part to be greater than 400 characters. If greater, i can split it every 4 period (not 6).

I found out a way to match the text every 6 periods, but i need the second part (the "no more than 400 charatcters).

```
((?:[^\.]+\.){6})
```

Could you help me?

Comment: It appears you wish to split the text every 6 sentences, provided the 6 sentences do not have more than 400 characters. If there is a group of 6 sentences that has more than 400 characters do you wish to limit that block to 4 sentences or limit all blocks to 4 sentences? Why 4 and not 3 or 5? What if a block of 4 sentences has more than 400 characters? What about sentences that end with a question or explanation mark? I'm not sure I would consider 5,000 characters to be a large text; *War and Peace* comes to mind when I think of large texts (about 3.5 million characters). :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should split at every period and then add either 4 or 6 parts of the split text.
Example:

```
text = 'a.b.c.d.e.f1231.g.h.i.j.k.l.m.n.o.p.q.r.s.t.u.v.w.x.y.z'

s = text.split('.')
res = []
index = 0
while index < len(s):
    part = '.'.join(s[index:index+4])
    part2 = '.'.join(s[index+4:index+6])
    if len(part) + len(part2) < 12:
        res.append(part+'.'+part2)
        index += 6
    else:
       res.append(part)
       index += 4
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but... i don't know how to use this code: i am a newbie and i use integromat to do those operation...